# Make XRDP connect to existing Xorg Server after a xrdp restart

Tags: xorg, xrdp

I run a Ubuntu 22.04 server with lubuntu desktop (LXQT). I have installed the latest XRDP using the extremely useful scrip provided by c-nergy.be. From time to time though XRDP will stop passing through the clipboard. When this happens I just do a systemctl restart xrdp and that fixes the clipboard issue. However, when I restart xrdp lose my rdp session with all my windows and apps that are running.

I discovered that when I start an RDP session to the server xrdp sets up a Xorg server:
/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :10 -auth .Xauthority -config xrdp/xorg.conf -noreset -nolisten tcp -logfile .xorgxrdp.%s.log

When I gracefully close my RDP client, Xorg :10 remains active, which means when I launch my RDP client again, I get connected to my last session with all my windows and apps still open. But if I have to restart XRDP using systemctl XRDP creates Xorg :11 despite Xorg :10 still being there. When I launch my RDP client after the restart, I get connected to Xorg :11.

I have spent the last few days researching the web and trying various suggestions related to sesman.ini, xrdp.ini and xorg.conf. These are just some of the suggestions I tried. I have even asked chatGPT!!

- specifying a default xorg display in xrdp.ini
- allowing multiple connections per server in xorg.conf
- specifying the display in sesman.ini: XorgParams=-config xrdp/xorg.conf -display :10 -auth .Xauthority -noreset

Sadly I am no closer to forcing XRDP to reuse the initial Xorg server it created. I hope someone here has solved this issue and can share their solution. Thank you